# Does anyone have information about a pre-1859 church in Villers-Bretonneux?

Tags: 19th-century, france, building

The current church of Villers-Bretonneux, Église Saint-Jean-Baptiste de [Villers-Bretonneux](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89glise_Saint-Jean-Baptiste_de_Villers-Bretonneux) was built after WWI. Before this was a church built in 1859; here is an historic [photo](https://www.awm.gov.au/collection/A02500).  There was a church in Villers-Bretonneux before 1859. The earlier church was used e.g. in Cassini's triangulation of France (see [p. 155](https://books.google.com/books?id=4TEVAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA155)).

Does anybody have some information (building time, drawing, position) of the pre-1859 church in Villers-Bretonneux?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can't provide any specific location information, but following some of the listed sources from the wiki article leads to a page [here](http://jpgourdain.fr/villersb.html) which does contain a drawing titled Ancient Church of Villers-Bretonneux:

[image]

There is some more information there, and perhaps someone with better knowledge of French can figure the source of the image out.

(**note** some possible redirection type stuff going on at this web-page for me, so be careful if you click on anything)